# Gradle: How to partition a task into sequentially executed actions

Tags: java, build-automation, gradle

Is it possible to nest tasks in gradle, such as

```
task foo(dependsOn: jar){
    // task 1
    // task 2
    // task 3
    .
    .
    .
    // task n
}
```

where the order of execution is `jar` > `foo` > `task 1` > `task 2` > `task 3` > ... > `task n`? I don't want the nested tasks (i.e. `task 1`, `task 2`, and etc.) to be exposed to the user. I only want the `foo` task to be exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in Gradle to only expose selected tasks (in the strict sense). There is, however, a way to only show selected tasks in `gradle tasks`. Unless the `--all` flag is used, `gradle tasks` will only show "root" tasks (i.e. tasks that no other task depends on) and tasks that have their `group` property set.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can simply do the following,

```
task foo(dependsOn: ['clean', 'jar']){
    foo << {
        println "First"
    }
    foo << {
        println "Second"
    }

    foo << {
        println "Third" 
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

where `<<` is shorthand for `doLast`. I think the neat thing about this approach is that only `foo` is exposed..the nested tasks remain hidden from the end user. And if you execute `foo`, you'll get

```
First
Second
Third
```

Comment: It's better to use `doLast` here than `foo <<`. What you are chaining here is task _actions_. This is different from chaining tasks, but can be the right tool depending on your needs.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, Thanks for the clarification about the fact that im chaining task actions, not tasks! :D